# unserialize cache zend doctrine2

Tags: zend-framework, serialization, doctrine-orm

Hi can you help me please! I want to use zend cache file since im in shared hosting.
So the problem is i cant retrieve cached doctrine file result. data has serialized coz it 's object. $cache->load($id) return as array i can't unserialize back. 
Please i will glad if you could help me or suggest something. Here my code.

```
$request    = $this->getRequest();
$slug   = $request->getParam('slug');

$front  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$bootstrap= $front->getParam('bootstrap');

$cache = $bootstrap->getResource('cachemanager')->getCache('content');

$cacheId   = md5('news_' . $slug);
if ( !($news = **unserialize($cache->load($cacheId))**) ) {

$news   = $this->_em->getRepository('Custom\Entity\News')
              ->findOneBySlug($slug);
    $cache->save($news, $cacheId);
var_dump('if u see me that mean not from cached');
 }

 $page = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(array(  
        'label'         => $news[0]->getTitle(),
        'route'     => 'news-view',
    'module'        => 'news',
    'controller'    => 'index',
    'action'        => 'view',
    'params'        => array(
        'slug' => $news[0]->getAlias())
        )
  );
 $page->setActive(false);
 $this->_helper->navigation->getContainer()
              ->findOneBy('uri', '/category/' . $news[0]->getCategory()->getSlug())
              ->addPage($page);

 $this->view->ogpa = new OpenGraphProtocolArticle();
 $this->view->news   = $news;
 $this->view->headTitle($news[0]->getTitle());
```

Comment: please help! here the cached data i got :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not save any Doctrine2 models in Zend_Cache see: https://ssmusoke.com/2012/03/25/doctrine2-day-3-proxies-associations-relationships/

This is because in the background Doctrine2 uses proxy classes which cannot be unserialized by the Zend auto loader, which will cause you a great deal of grief ...

If you are to cache anything, cache the output not the models.

Comment: can you provide any example about output caching for zend framework?

Comment: thanks you @ssmusoke for your answer. It's the solution i finally adopted. but caching output dont stop database queries for this resource each time user request same thing. But you right since im in share hosting i cant do better...

Comment: @Optimus just create a view helper where you put cache option and then in your view use

 `code`<?php if (!$this->cacheOutput()->start('news_' . md5($this->slug) )) : ?>
    data i want to cache
    <?php $this->cacheOutput()->end(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: `code`
  class Custom_View_Helper_CacheOutput extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

 /**
  * @var Zend_View_Interface 
  */
 public $view;

 /**
  *  
  */
 public function cacheOutput()
 {
  $front    = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
  
  $cache   = $bootstrap->getResource('cachemanager')
           ->getCache('content');
  return $cache;
 }

 /**
  * Sets the view field 
  * @param $view Zend_View_Interface
  */
 public function setView(Zend_View_Interface $view) {
  $this->view = $view;
 }
    }
`code`
this is my view helper

Comment: @MarcelDjaman thanks for the code but isn't the action executed before rending the view? I mean you can cache the view but the entity will always be loaded in the controller action.

Comment: @Optimus touché!!! that i want to avoid but seems like for my environment is the best i can do! i will keep dig.